# Multiple choice of instances of another model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Car` model where one of the properties is `horsepower`. I also have a `Horsepower` model. I want my car model to choose from a list of `Horsepower` instances.

```
class Horsepower(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  ...

class Car(models.Model):
  ...
  horsepower = models.ManyToManyField(Horsepower)
```

I don't want to use ManytoManyField because there should only be one selection.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nandesuka- This might work.

```
 class Car(models.Model):
      ...
      horsepower = models.ForeignKey(Horsepower,.....)
```